# Adding a column from another file

Tags: bash, perl, awk, insert

i have the following problem :

There is a file, tab delimited :

```
Code1  Number1  Name1  Phone1
Code2  Number2  Name2  Phone2
Code3  Number3  Name3  Phone3
Code4  Number4  Name4  Phone4
```

And i have a file :

```
Surname 1
Surname 2
Surname 3
Surname 4
```

My desired output is :

```
Code1  Number1  Name1 Surname1 Phone1
Code1  Number1  Name1 Surname2 Phone1
Code1  Number1  Name1 Surname3 Phone1
Code1  Number1  Name1 Surname4 Phone1
```

I know i propably have to use awk for this, but i only know how to insert a column of one fixed value in between others, using the :

```
awk '{ $2=$2"newvalue" print $0 }'
```

But i have no idea how to read lines from the other file and storing them in newvalue to pull the above desired output off. I do not require an awk specific advise. Thanks for the help.

Comment: How do you match the records or rows in the files?

Comment: Updated the question, the two files are sorted and just need to be mixed, the first row of the second file going in the first row of the first file, after "Name 1".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWK only:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[FNR]=$1$2;next} {print $1,$2,$3,a[FNR],$4}' file2 file1
Code1 Number1 Name1 Surname1 Phone1
Code2 Number2 Name2 Surname2 Phone2
Code3 Number3 Name3 Surname3 Phone3
Code4 Number4 Name4 Surname4 Phone4
```

Answer (score 5):

with paste and awk;

```
user@host:/tmp$ paste file1 file2 | awk '{print $1, $2, $3, $5$6, $4}' | column -t
Code1  Number1  Name1  Surname1  Phone1
Code1  Number1  Name1  Surname2  Phone1
Code1  Number1  Name1  Surname3  Phone1
Code1  Number1  Name1  Surname4  Phone1
```

paste is used to join files

column -t is used to pretty formatting;

Answer (score 2):

Just `cut` and `paste`:

```
$ paste <(cut -f 1-3 a) b <(cut -f 4 a)
Code1   Number1 Name1   Surname 1       Phone1
Code2   Number2 Name2   Surname 2       Phone2
Code3   Number3 Name3   Surname 3       Phone3
Code4   Number4 Name4   Surname 4       Phone4
```

Output delimiters are tabs. Space after `Surname`s can be dealt with piping above to `tr -d \`.

Answer (score 1):

**using paste and vim**

```
$ paste file1 file2 > newfile.txt
```

**then open newfile.txt in vim**

then do a regex substituiton as follows

```
:%s/\(.*\)\t\(.*\)\t\(.*\)\t\(.*\)\t\(.*\)/\1\t\2\t\3\t\5\6\t\4
```